# 500 Internal server error - Request Timeout CURL PHP

Tags: php, server, centos7

Hello I need some into about this error. I send loop data using curl that data take too much time to send. I set `max_execution_time` Limit to 900. So why this Request Timeout happen. Is that server problem or `php.ini` problem.

NOTE: My Proxy is Working and its high speed. I send data in loop. So after 1mint this error show. in title say `500 Internal server error` and in body says `Request Timeout`

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Opera/9.80 (Series 60; Opera Mini/6.5.27309/34.1445; U; en) Presto/2.8.119 Version/11.10');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

echo  $data = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Show the code causing this time-out, you likely have an infinite loop of something.

Comment: i update my question check again thanks

Comment: looks fine. Might be your proxy that's slowing things down.

Comment: Your title says "500 Internal server error", and your question text says "this Request Timeout". Please can you [edit] your question to include *the actual error message you're seeing*, and update the title to be more specific.

Comment: Are you really using a proxy? Does it need to be authenticated to?  Can you get to $url successfully through a browser? Using the same proxy?

Comment: Yes i am using proxy and its public proxy no auth need

Comment: Verify your proxy setting is correct by trying a different target URL first, if it works, verify you can access the $url by your browser and without proxy. But pretty sure your proxy is just not responding at all.

Comment: You've edited the title, but your text still says "this error". *What* error? You need to be specific; remember that we only have the information you give us, none of the things that are obvious to you because you've been staring at them for hours.

Comment: I re-update this hope you understand this time thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might change your curl timeout from 10 seconds (like you have it inside your code right now) from

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
```

to 900 seconds, like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 900);
```

These numbers are seconds (not 100% sure). Also find according curl documentation [here](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_TIMEOUT.html).

Comment: From the manual "*CURLOPT_TIMEOUT: The maximum number of **seconds** to allow cURL functions to execute.*" - so you're right on that count!